# How do i implement a database for my ios app?

Tags: ios, database

So i created my first app which allows users to track there fitness information (workouts, routines, etc). I want take my app to the next step by allowing the user to create there own account and be able to access their workouts from any ios device (all they have to do is log in). I know i have to use databases, but I just don't know where or how to start this process.

Could you recommend any tutorials or perhaps a resource you used to teach yourself? I'm familiar with sql (took a course on it in university.

thanks guys, I apologize for the newb question.

Comment: coredata...............

Comment: What have you looked at so far?

Comment: I know how to write sql queries to store and manipulate data. The course i took focused heavily on relational algebra though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many third-party services you can use that can take care of the backend for your app so that you don't need to worry about managing the database yourself. Two of the most popular ones are parse and stackmob. Take a look at their documentations. I personally use parse and would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never written any os apps, but for applications in general.
There are many ways, one of which is getting a server/website (you can get free ones) and set up the MYSQL database to have the tables you need like users etc.
Then simply send requests via POST/GET to the server which will enter it into the database.Then when they want to login just do the reverse.

I would personally uses sockets, and probably encrypt the data. You may as-well send information such as how long they've used the app for etc.